# Rails 4 Update Lambda Expression for has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, has-many, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I updated my `Rails` app from version `Rails 3.0` to `Rails 4.1` and I've got the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :for...
```

The problem appears in the following line:

```
has_many :downloads, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "downloads.position DESC"
```

After a little google research, the line looks like this:

```
has_many :downloads, :dependent => :destroy, -> {order('downloads.position DESC')}
```

And now I've got the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC
```

I also tried other variations but nothing worked. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the ordering of lambda would resolve your issue:

```
has_many :downloads, -> {order('downloads.position DESC')}, :dependent => :destroy
```

Notice that I have moved the lamda before `:dependent => :destroy` which is a hash (key-value). When you place the lambda after the hash(which is not delimited my curly braces {}), Ruby would expect the next value(i.e., lambda in your case) to again be a key-value pair thinking that its the continuation of hash and it obviously complaints when it doesn't find the next value to be key-value pair and that is what is happening in your case.